# Accessing variable in another namespace C#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, function, namespaces

I know this has been discussed many times on here, I've tried to set my variables as public etc. but I can't seem to be able to use it in my other name space. I'd appreciate if you could give me some tips (I'm a noob at C#)
The string i'm trying access from my other name space is "stringatlinei"

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.Mail;
using ConsoleApplication32;





namespace ConsoleApplication32

{
public class Program
{




    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirSearch(@"C:\\Users\\");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }





    static void DirSearch(string dir)
    {
        try
        {

            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);

                DirSearch(d);

                // Compose a string that consists of three lines.
                string lines = d;

                // Write the string to a file.
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new         
               System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt", true);
                file.WriteLine(lines);

                file.Close();

                var oldLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt");
                var newLines = oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains("Windows"));
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt", newLines);

                var oldLines4 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt");
                var newLines4 = oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains("$Recycle.Bin"));
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt", newLines4);

                var oldLines7 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt");
                var newLines7 = oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains("Program Files"));
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt", newLines7);

                var oldLines8 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt");
                var newLines8 = oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains("Program Files (x86)"));
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt", newLines8);

                var oldLines9 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt");
                var newLines9 = oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains("AppData"));
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt", newLines9);













            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);


        }



        var lineCount = File.ReadLines(@"c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt").Count();
        Console.WriteLine(lineCount);
        Console.ReadLine();
        int element = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lineCount + 1; i++)

        {

            element = element + 1;
            String stringAtLinei = File.ReadLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(element);
            Console.WriteLine(stringAtLinei);

        }




        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "random command example thing";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();





        }
    }
}
```

then the other namespace etc.

Answer (score 0):

"stringatlinei" is not a property, or a public anything, it is defined inside a loop inside a function.

Try public static string stringatlinei="", then just assign in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing that variable in another namespace is not possible.  You should read up on the basics, scope in particular, to understand why this is so.  Here's a helpful article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

Basically, your variable you are trying access is created inside your `for` loop.  Each iteration of your loop, it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the part you should change: (I removed the rest for clarity)

```
namespace ConsoleApplication32
{
    public class Program
    {
        public String stringAtLinei;

        static void DirSearch(string dir)
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < lineCount + 1; i++)
             {
                  stringAtLinei = File.ReadLines("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test.txt").ElementAtOrDefault(element);

             }
        }
    }
}
```

The point is that you can access fields and properties of a class, but not variables that are confined to the method they're in. So I changed the variable to be a field in the class.

Comment: thanks I'll try it out when i get access to my computer and visual studio. I was about to give up